# Cytoscape java: Draw edges all to way to the center of nodes

Tags: java, graph-visualization, cytoscape

I have tried to style my network graph in Cytoscape java (version 3.8.1) on macOS (version 10.15.7) but am unable to have edges drawn all the way to the center of the nodes, such as they end up appearing full. Right now they appear truncated.

It's especially hard to search for as all results usually concern the sister project `Cytoscape.js`.

This is the current state of my visualization:

[image: basic]

This is the desired state done up manually in a paint software:

[image: modified]

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: You can send the creators of Cytoscape an email explaining the problem.  If this was your drawing code, I'd say draw the edges first, then draw the nodes

Comment: There is none of my code involved here, I simply used the java GUI to obtain this result. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The Cytoscape dev team reviewed this issue today. We purposely do not draw edges to the center for a few reasons, including interactive performance and use cases with semi-transparent nodes (where the edges when then become visible under the nodes).

Some workarounds:

- Version 3.7.2 had rounded ends, which you may or may not find more appealing
- If you use circular nodes, the ends are more symmetrical, which you may or may not find more appealing

Comment: Thanks for your review and comment. In the end we did in fact go for circular nodes, even if the text labels would thus not be able to nicely fit inside of them. You could consider a boolean option to draw them to the center that is off by default.